# generating 'random' number using modulo from a stream of odd numbers

Tags: c++, c

i want to generate a pseudo-random bool stream based on a modulo operation on another stream of integers (say X), so the operation would be

```
return ( X % 2);
```

The only problem is that X is a stream of integers that always ends in 1, so for instance would be somehing like 1211, 1221, 1231, 1241 .... is there a way for me to disregard the last bit (without using string manip) so the test doesnt always pass or always fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd otherwise be happy to use the last bits, use the penultimate bits instead:

```
return (x & 0x2) >> 1;
```

So say the next number from your stream is 23:

```
  1 0 1 1 1  // 23 in binary
& 0 0 0 1 0  // 0x2 in binary
-----------
  0 0 0 1 0
```

Shifting that right by one bit (`>> 1`) gives 1. With 25, the answer would be 0:

```
  1 1 0 0 1
& 0 0 0 1 0
-----------
  0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: so convert to binary and then ... sorry, dont quite follow

Comment: Basically this gives you back the second-last bit.

Comment: Could be written as `return x & 0x2 ? 1 : 0` for more clarity.

Comment: I'd say that's actually less clear. I'd just use `bool(x & 0x02)`

Comment: Or `(x >> 1) & 1`, but an optimizing compiler will probably see that they're all the same.

Answer (score 3):

How about `(X / 10) % 2` then?

Comment: tried that - i guess because its dropping of the remainder that doesnt work either...

Comment: Why wouldn't that work? It will work with the stream of numbers in your example.

Comment: its strange, its always returning the odd test as true, still.

Comment: So are you sure the numbers you posted are truly representative?

Comment: Obviously not: (1221 / 10) % 2 == 122 % 2 == 0.

Comment: (1220 /10) % 2 == 122 % 2 == 0 also though (so it doesnt flip)

Comment: But your numbers end in the digit `1`, so `1220` isn't possible, is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
return ( x%20/10 );
```